# How to safely clean electrical equipment

Tags: cleaning

I’ve got some MCCB circuit breakers similar to the one in the photo attached which could do with a good clean.

What’s the safest way to clean something like this ? I was thinking isopropyl, but not sure if I should’ve considering anything else ?

If I were to use isopropyl, is there any particular spec or % I should get?

[image: MCCB that needs to be cleaned]

Comment: I use isopropanol on electronics all the time.  Cleans and leaves no residue.  You can get nearly 100% pure (no water) at any good drug store.  It might attack the labels so use sparingly.   NOTE ISO IS SUPER FLAMMABLE LIKE GASOLINE FLAMABLE.   Do not power up until it completely evaporates.  And don't breath it.  In this case I'd try just a damp water rag first though.  Don't get it inside

Comment: do not use `rubbing alcohol` because it contains oil

Comment: first, vacuum the breaker while scrubbing with a brush

Comment: +1 on isopropanol for anything electronics related except for speakers and microphones.

Comment: Solvents will remove the lubration inside this breaker and make it unreliable

Answer (score 4):

Damp microfiber cloth. Not so wet that it leaves anything but a thin film of moisture at the surface.

This more or less ensures that no water will enter the device itself. Cleaning the surface is probably enough, as MCCB's tend to be rather dust-proof.

You don't need alcohol or anything fancy for wiping off dust; water will do just fine. If it's oily, alcohol is a excellent de-greaser that evaporates quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I would clean it best I could with a vacuum, then wipe it with a damp cloth using distilled water then wipe it again with a dry, lint free cloth, this should get most of the crud off of it. Then detail it with at least 91% or stronger isopropyl alcohol. After I would bake it at about 65C for a few hours, it appears it had gotten wet in its past life.